# PHP/MySQL Latest photos friends

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking, photos

Photos: id, uid, date;

Friends: uid1, uid2, date, status;

I want show latest photos for friends of user. How do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Photos AS p, Friends AS f
WHERE p.uid = f.uid2 AND f.uid1 = ${userX.id}
ORDER BY p.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: please, use joins instead of `select`ing from multiple tables: `SELECT p.id FROM Photos AS p JOIN Friends as f ON p.uid = f.uid2 WHERE f.uid1 = ${userX.id} ORDER BY p.date DESC`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id FROM photos WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friends WHERE uid1 = {$uid1} ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1);

I supposed that UID1 is the User and UID2 is the friend, this will retrieve all the IDs

Comment: while correct, the nested select statement is executed repeatedly depending on the databases' implementation, which can affect performance quite drasticly.

Comment: you're too much right, your answer is the right way to do that